# Prevent redirect response with Alamofire in Swift

Tags: swift, redirect, alamofire

I'm looking for example code how to prevent redirect response (status code 3xx) when request web api. I'm using Swift with Alamofire 1.2. 
I have tried:

```
delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = { (session: NSURLSession!, task: NSURLSessionTask!, response: NSHTTPURLResponse!, request: NSURLRequest!) in
            return nil
        }
```

but not work

I've also tried: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/350/files and have changed my own code to:

```
    var acc = self.txtAccount.text
    var pwd = self.txtPassword.text
    var url : String = "http://10.1.0.2:8081/wordpress/wp-json/users/me"
    let delegate = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.delegate
    delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = { (session: NSURLSession!, task: NSURLSessionTask!, response: NSHTTPURLResponse!, request: NSURLRequest!) in

        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        var credential = "\(acc):\(pwd)"
        var authData = credential.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var encodedAuthData = authData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
        var authValue = "Basic \(encodedAuthData!)"

        request.setValue(authValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        return request
    }

    //I've implemented URLRequestConvertible 'Router'. it also have call the same above url
    Alamofire.request(Router.Authorize(acc, pwd))
        .response({(request, response, data, error) in
            println(request)
        })
```

But it's not worked and seem like turned to infinite loop. I tested on Charles.

Comment: If you drop a `println("Redirection is calling my closure")` inside that closure, do you see that it is being called? Or placing a breakpoint?

Comment: The `delegate` can be nil if you haven't set it

Answer (score 5):

Alternative (code snippet) solution using AlamoFire 2.4 (Xcode7). In my case, I always expect a redirect. (I am unpacking a shortened link.) If the completion in the request.response call runs, that is an error to me.

```
func printRedirectUrl() {

    // taskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionWithCompletion: ((NSURLSession, NSURLSessionTask, NSHTTPURLResponse, NSURLRequest, NSURLRequest? -> Void) -> Void)?
    Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionWithCompletion = { session, task, response, request, completion in
        // request.URL has the redirected URL inside of it, no need to parse the body
        print("REDIRECT Request: \(request)")
        if let url = request.URL {
            print("Extracted URL: \(url)")
        }
        Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = nil // Restore redirect abilities
        return
    }

    // We expect a redirect, so the completion of this call should never execute
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://google.com")
    let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, url!)
    request.response { request, response, data, error in
        print("Logic Error, response should NOT have been called for request: \(request)")
        Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = nil // Restore redirect abilities - just in case
    }
}
```

> REDIRECT Request:  { URL: https://www.google.com/ }
>
> Extracted URL: https://www.google.com/

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4,

```
let delegate = Alamofire.SessionManager.default.delegate

        delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = { (session, task, response, request) -> URLRequest? in
           // print("REDIRECT Request: \(request)")
            return nil
        }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks, pal!

Answer (score 3):

Hello its actually pretty simple

Alamofire has a redirector that will

Example

```swift
let request = AF.request("https://google.com",method: .post,parameters: parameters)
.cURLDescription { description in
            debugPrint(description)
        }
        let redirector = Redirector(behavior: .doNotFollow)
        request.redirect(using: redirector)
```

with that it wont redirect

its also in the docs in the advanced usage section

Answer (score 2):

It looks like returning `nil` can possibly cause a deadlock. Instead, try to create a new `NSURLRequest` with the same original URL. See @jhersh's [notes](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/350) in a previous Alamofire PR along with the comments and implementation in his [tests](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/350/files).

#### How to Stop a Redirect

```
func disallowRedirect() {
    let URL = "http://google.com/"
    let delegate = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.delegate

    delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = { session, task, response, request in
        return NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: URL)!)
    }

    let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, URL)
    request.response { request, response, data, error in
        println("Request: \(request)")
        println("Response: \(response)")
        println("Data: \(NSString(data: data as! NSData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))")
        println("Error: \(error)")
    }
}

disallowRedirect()
```

The fact that you cannot pass `nil` into the `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` method's `completionHandler` looks like a bug. I'm going to file a radar for this and I'll post a link to the bug report once I'm finished.

Comment: So the solution is I create a dummy NSURLRequest inside taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection?
And How could I get the response data inside the taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection. because I only get the response data of the redirected request in response handler of class Request

Comment: You don't want to get the response data inside `taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection`. You want to get it in your response serializer. If you properly disable the redirection, you should receive the response from the original request. See this [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/RequestChanges.html) for more info.

Comment: At first, I want to disable the redirection and receive the response data inside `response` method.
And after your above comment mentioned returnning nil cause deadlock, @jhersh's test also have comment `+            // TODO: URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:
+            // suggests that returning nil should refuse the redirect, but this causes a deadlock/timeout
+`
so I am looking for how to access original request's data inside `taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection` . 
Now you suggest me to disable the redirection. I wonder how can I do this?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how to stop a redirect. I've tested this in a playground and it works as expected.

Comment: Dear friend, the code seem like turn into infinite loop. I updated my question more clearly. I couldn't test on PG because don't know how to import alamofire on PG

Comment: @khangcv, there's a playground in the Alamofire project itself. All you need to do is either download the project, or clone it from Github. Then open the workspace, then the Playground inside. Paste in the code I wrote, and it will work as expected. Since you're seeing an infinite loop with your code, I'd suggest you just try returning that first line where you creating the `NSURLRequest`. Maybe by adding all the other headers and such, you are technically triggering another request? I'm not entirely sure since I can't try your code.

Comment: When I test on alamorefire playground and use example url: google.com, the result is the message Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1007 "too many HTTP redirects" . Request looped about 16 times and stopped.

Comment: Hmmm...maybe it is having an issue in the playground. I did see that once as well, then I relaunched the playground and saw the appropriate behavior from then on out (probably 10 times). Maybe it would be a good idea to drop it into an actual project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your version of Alamofire has a support for public delegate. Last time I checked delegate was private. I am using the changes made by @jhersh. You can check his additions and how to use delegate by followin github pr. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/314

Comment: The delegate and it's various override closures were opened up officially in the Alamofire 1.2.0 release.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Since I am using with iOS 7 I can't directly use the release I use my own version with struct etc to mimic framework.