# Prevent Alamofire from redirecting

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Im using Swift with AlamoFire (Latest Version) and do a Post to authenticate with a websservice. What drives me nuts is that AlamoFire follows a redirect and the response doesn't contain the actual response (302 FOUND) but the content from the redirected page.

I want to prevent AlamoFire from using the redirect and instead print the header of the original response to read the cookies from there.

Thanks

Comment: See this discussion: [Prevent redirect response with Alamofire in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845768/prevent-redirect-response-with-alamofire-in-swift)

Comment: I am also looking for the solution. What are your findings. `Alamofire (~> 4.0)`